# convert one list of strings into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this list:

```
['>A0A017H360\n',
'IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIMMMMMMMOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOMMMMMMMMMIIMMMMMMMMMMMOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOMMMMMMMMMIIIIIIIMMMMMMMOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOMMMMMMMMMMMIIIIIMMMMMMMMMMMOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOMMMMMMMMMMMIIIMMMMMMMMMMMOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOMMMMMMMMMIIMMMMMMMMMOOOOOMMMMMMMMMMMIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII\n',
'>A0A076JBG3\n',
'IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIMMMMMMMMMOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOMMMMMMMMMMMIIIMMMMMMMMMMMOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOMMMMMMMMMIIMMMMMMMMMOOOOOMMMMMMMIIIMMMMMMMMMMMOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOMMMMMMMMMMMIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII\n',
'>A0A0H7CCS8\n',
'IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIMMMMMMMOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOMMMMMMMMMMMIIIIIMMMMMMMMMOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOMMMMMMMMMMMIIIMMMMMMMMMMMMMOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOMMMMMMMMMMMIIIMMMMMMMMMMMOOOOOOOOOOOOOMMMMMMMMMIIIIIII\n',
'>A0A0J3ZJ69\n',
'IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIMMMMMMMMMOOOOOOOOOOOOOOMMMMMMMMMIIIMMMMMMMMMMMOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOMMMMMMMMMMMIIIMMMMMMMMMMMOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOMMMMMMMMMMMIIIMMMMMMMMMOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOMMMMMMMMMMMIIIMMMMMMMMMOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOMMMMMMMMM\n',
'>A0A129GXB6\n',
'IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIMMMMMMMMMOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOMMMMMMMMMIIMMMMMMMMMMMOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOMMMMMMMIIMMMMMMMMMMMOOOOOMMMMMMMMMIIMMMMMMMMMOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOMMMMMMMMMIIIIIIIMMMMMMMMMOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOMMMMMMMMMMM\n',
'>F9D0S9\n',
'IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII....]
```

It is a list of strings in which I have names and sequences which belong to the names that precede them. How can I build a dictionary in which the keys are the names and the values are the strings?
Thank you

Comment: where is the code you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the elements of the list are always alternations of names and sequences you can do this:

```
{ key: elem for key, elem in zip(your_list[0::2],your_list[1::2]) }
```

`your_list[0::2]` will generate a list with the names, `your_list[1::2]` will generate a list with the sequences.

`zip(your_list[0::2],your_list[1::2])` will create a list of tuples `(name, sequence)` and then you can iterate over them with `{ key: elem for key, elem in ...}` to generate the dict.